# Boosting performance via memory capture?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, performance, memory

In my WPF application, there are heavy custom controls that take time to get constructed, therefore it will affect user experience while visiting pages with large number of objects ..

So, I've took a look at MS PowerPoint, I saw  temp files that are stored while user interact with presentation, I think that PP team used those files to boost up the speed of pages construction.

The question is, is it possible to take a memory capture of specific instances and store captures to files, then to re-populate memory to get my app instances live again?

Aren't those heavy visual trees stored in memory? isn't there a way to retrieve memory rather than dispose and re-build each control?

I've searched for WPF performance tips, didn't get any clue about this approach.

Any idea?

Comment: I/O is slow, so storing something to disk will only improve performance if creating the same thing directly in memory takes longer. Why does the construction of your custom controls take so much time? Did you measure it?

Comment: It takes seconds! I've measured it, we need to do re-deisig for some issues, but construction speed for controls is not fast, specially for rich text controls .. so I think I/O might be faster than constructing controls .. at least we can try ..

Comment: Keep clam and start those benchmarks! ;)

Comment: Construction takes time, think about recycling of data templates in virtualization, it does matter ..

Comment: Before making things worse by "optimizing" irrelevant parts, attach a profiler and *measure*!

Comment: I've already profiled and measured, I found things that can be enhanced, and I found long time at constructors too, I can fix profiled elements, but I have no idea how to speed up constructors

Comment: One common reason for poor performance is how you deal with resources in WPF. Just as a hint, it might make sense to take a look at what's going on here. Depending on your structure it can happen that massive resource dictionaries are instantiated with each construction of a control... http://pelebyte.net/blog/2011/07/11/twelve-ways-to-improve-wpf-performance/#ResourceDictionary, Bullet Point No. 6. The list is a good starting point, anyways.

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I will check that list ..